# Idiomatic way to deal with a two way mapping

Tags: elixir

I have defined module and struct like so:

```
defmodule User do
  defstruct [:id, :name, :email, :photo]

  def labels, do: [:user]
end
```

There is a labels method so that I am able to map to and from a database record. If I need to insert a `%User{}` struct into the database, I'm able to grab the `user.__struct__` property and call `labels` on it so I know what labels the record needs to have.

However, I'm not sure how to go the other way... given that I have a bare record with the label `:user`, how do I map that back to the `User` struct?

For now I could declare a hash with all of these mappings, but it would be nice to define the mapping on the `User` struct itself.

Note: I'd rather not follow a convention by came-casing the label because (1) it's not explicit and (2) it feels fragile.

Thanks!

Comment: `User` is the atom returned by the `__struct__` function. Why not just use that? No mapping required.

Comment: Given a `User`, I have no problem getting the `:user` label. However, the reverse is the challenge. I lookup a raw record from the database which has no knowledge of the `User` object. I just have the `:user` label and need to know that the `:user` label atom is associated with the `User` module atom.

Comment: Right, so I was suggesting to use `User` instead of `:user` as your label. Then you don't need any mapping.

Comment: This may not be immediately possible, as we have a legacy system which relies on pre-existing labels. It's not a clean 1-1 mapping. Also it's a curiosity for me as to how this could be accomplished :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of two relatively straightforward ways to do this.

### One

Simply declare the list of labeled records somewhere (`labeled_records = [User, Photo, ...]`, and build a map by using the `record_module.labels` return values as your keys (and the record module aliases themselves as the values).

You'll be repeating yourself slightly with the struct names, but at least you don't need to worry about keeping the label-to-record map in sync, since you generate it dynamically from the source-of-truth `record_module.labels` functions.

### Deux

Inspired by the `Mix.Tasks.Help` implementation.

Make all your records start with the same prefix, e.g. `MyApp.Records.User`, `MyApp.Records.Photo`, etc. Then, at runtime, to find the record module for a given label, first find the `.beam` files with the aforementioned prefix. Then, call `.labels` on the matching modules to match against the input label.

NOTE: Of course, if you want to use this in production, you should cache the results of `.beam` file traversal instead of doing it every time you need to go from label -> record. Below is just a POC.

*records.ex:*

```
defmodule MyApp.Records.User do
  defstruct [:id, :name, :email, :photo]
  def labels, do: [:user, :person]
end

defmodule MyApp.Records.Photo do
  defstruct [:id, :user_id, :url]
  def labels, do: [:photo, :pic]
end
```

*record_finder.ex:*

```
defmodule MyApp.RecordFinder do
  defp record_module_from_path(filename) do
    base = String.replace_suffix(Path.basename(filename), ".beam", "")
    prefix = "Elixir.MyApp.Records."
    if String.starts_with?(base, prefix), do: String.to_atom(base)
  end

  defp get_record_modules do
    for(dir <- :code.get_path,
        {:ok, files} = :erl_prim_loader.list_dir(to_char_list(dir)),
        file <- files,
        mod = record_module_from_path(file),
        do: mod)
    |> Enum.uniq
  end

  def module_from_label(label) do
    Enum.find get_record_modules, fn m ->
      label in m.labels
    end
  end
end
```

*Test script:*

```
Enum.each [:user, :person, :photo, :pic], fn label ->
  module = MyApp.RecordFinder.module_from_label(label)
  IO.puts "#{label}: #{module}"
end
```

*Output:*

```
user: Elixir.MyApp.Records.User
person: Elixir.MyApp.Records.User
photo: Elixir.MyApp.Records.Photo
pic: Elixir.MyApp.Records.Photo
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you would define such mapping within the struct itself. If you didn't know to look at the `User` struct, then how would a map within that struct help you find it?

Seems like a map of labels to modules is the right way to go.

You could build the map at compile time using macros or at run time by finding all the modules that have a `labels` function and adding each label/module pair to the map. That would prevent the need to separately maintain the map.